# Error handling with 'tryCatch' clashes with user pressing 'STOP' in RStudio

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I am working on a webscraping project, and I made a function to handle errors when webscraping using `GET`. My problem is that the error handling treats me pressing the 'STOP' button in RStudio as an error, and handles this by waiting. I would like to be allowed to stop the function from executing.

Here is the function:

```
# Handle read_html errors
get_page <- function(url, user_agent = "[my information]", skipped) {
  headers <- add_headers(`User-Agent` = user_agent)
  
  if (!exists(skipped, envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
    assign(skipped, c(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
  
  for (attempt in 1:4) {
    start_time <<- Sys.time()
    tryCatch({
      response <- GET(url, headers = headers)
      http_code <- response$status_code
      
      if (http_code == 200) {
        page <- read_html(rawToChar(response$content))
        return(page)
        
      } else if (http_code %in% c(400, 401, 403, 404)) {
        cat("HTTP", http_code, "error for", url, "\n")
        assign(skipped, c(get(skipped), url), envir = .GlobalEnv)
        return(NULL)
      }

    }, error = function(e) {
      cat("Error:", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
      Sys.sleep(60)  # Wait before retrying
      
      if (attempt == 4) {
        cat("Skipped", url, "\n")
        assign(skipped, c(get(skipped), url), envir = .GlobalEnv)
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

When I press 'STOP', console prints this mesage `Error: Operation was aborted by an application callback` then waits 60 seconds and tries again. I can only make the function stop by forcefully terminating RStudio.

I have tried making the function allow me to stop it by adding:

```
# ... first part of my code

    return(NULL)
  }

  }, error = function(e) {
      if (inherits(e, "interrupt")) {
        cat("Execution interrupted by user.\n")
        return(NULL) 
      } else {
        cat("Error:", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
        Sys.sleep(60)  

# ... rest of the code
```

... and:

```
# ... first part of my code

  }, interrupts = function(e) {
      cat("Interrupted by the user\n")
      return(NULL)
    }, error = function(e) {
      cat("Error:", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
      Sys.sleep(60)  # Wait before retrying

# ... rest of my code
```

But when I scrape and pres 'STOP', e.g. in this loop, it does exactly the same as before (prints message `Error: Operation was aborted by an application callback` then waits 60 seconds and tries again)

```
for (i in 0:143) {
  progress(i, 0:143)
  url <- paste0(base, i)
  page <- get_page(url, skipped = "skip_excel_au")
  
  url_pers <- c(url_pers,
                page %>% html_nodes("a.link.person") %>% html_attr("href") 
  )
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
}
```